# How to convert CSS effect to Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to convert a **CSS effect** to a **javascript** code.

I want to automatically leave a section when the page is loaded. That is, once the board is loaded with the same effect round one div. You can go to Hover Me to see the CSS effect.

If you can not use the library, I want to see what happens in the code

Can I help you add my JavaScript / jQuery code now?

Thanks

```css
html{
    background: #080808;
}

div {
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
div::before, div::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.draw {
    transition: color 0.25s;
}
.draw::before, .draw::after {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.draw::before {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.draw::after {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.draw:hover {
    color: #60daaa;
}
.draw:hover::before, .draw:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.draw:hover::before {
    border-top-color: #60daaa;
    border-right-color: #60daaa;
    transition: width 0.25s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
}
.draw:hover::after {
    border-bottom-color: #60daaa;
    border-left-color: #60daaa;
}

.meet:hover {
    color: #fbca67;
}
.meet::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.meet:hover::before {
    border-top-color: #fbca67;
    border-right-color: #fbca67;
}
.meet:hover::after {
    border-bottom-color: #fbca67;
    border-left-color: #fbca67;
    transition: height 0.25s ease-out, width 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit-rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="top">
    <div onload="loading()" id="iki" class="draw meet">Hover Me</div>
    <script src="js/uikit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First check if the elemnt is hovered like `var isHovered = $('#elem').is(":hover");` where `isHovered` return true or false and then scrollTo where you want to like `$('body').scrollTo(500);`..is this what you need?

Comment: I did not get it right. Can code .
not scroll . just header

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution for this,

1) Change all your `:hover` to `.hover`

2) Then add this class using **JavaScript**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  document.querySelectorAll('.draw')[0].classList.add('hover');
});
```

Found a similar answer [How to execute CSS3 animation onLoad instead of hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27629717/3677277)

Comment: can you explain a bit more the term automatic load?

Comment: i want [link](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/aphrodite-royal-website-style/full_screen_preview/19296664?_ga=2.44143652.101112532.1532415675-1950426576.1531656269)

please see page header

Comment: So you want it to load without hover, once the page started, it must load, right ?

Comment: exactly . i want  load without hover

Comment: Updated the answer, check now